# Is there anyway to transport completed levels on my computer over to my phone?

Tags: candy-crush-saga

I am on level 1758 online on my computer and only on level 40 on my phone app.

Is there anyway to transport all the levels on my computer that are completed over to my phone?

Answer (score 1):

Logging into Facebook in both your PC save and your Mobile save should automatically sync progress between both systems.